# Pandas: How to Format 2 types of Dates?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

**How to convert these two different date-formats to one?**

*I'm using:*

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format = "%d-%m")
```

*and it returns:*

```
ValueError: time data '22.03.' does not match format '%m-%d' (match)
```

...My date column has two different types of dates displayed:

```
   0          22.03.
   1          22.03.
              ...    
   448    10.09.2021
   449    09.09.2021
```

I don't need to display the year, so DATE.MONTH -format would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create datetiems in both formats with `errors='coerce'` and replace missing values another `Series`:

```
s1 = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format = "%d.%m.", errors='coerce')
s2 = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format = "%d.%m.%Y", errors='coerce')
df["date"] = s1.fillna(s2)

print (df)
          date
0   1900-03-22
1   1900-03-22
448 2021-09-10
449 2021-09-09
```